# Building SQL query with multiple WHERE requirements, one a bit complex, lost

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm working on a homework problem where

> I need to poll three tables and find names of students who have less
>   than 3.5 GPA and are taking less than 9 credit hours

I've figured out how to populate the names of the students who have less than 9 credit hours, but I'm stuck on figuring out their credit hours.

The **Student** table contains `Student ID` (primary key), `Name`, `Year` (fresh, soph, etc), `Major`, and `GPA`.

The **Course** table contains `course ID` (primary key), `Name of class`, and the `credit hour rating for that class`.

The **Enrollment** table contains the `Student ID` (made this a foreign key), `Course1` (FK), `Course2`, `Course3`, and `Course4`.

I'm not looking for the 'correct' answer, but some sense of direction.

My query so far is

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME 
From StudentTable,EnrollmentTable,CourseTable
WHERE (GPA <3.5)
```

I'm thinking I need something after that GPA check, to analyze the  EnrollmentTable for each student, check each course (Course1, Course2, etc), if !null, use that courseID and poll the Course Table to find the credit value for that course. Then use SUM to check to see if <9.

Thoughts? Thanks for any and all help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to get the sum of the credit hours for a given student, which should lead you to think about a group by

Lets break it down.  To start with, you want the students with < 3.5 GPA, that's simple its just:

```
SELECT S.Id, S.Name
FROM Student S
WHERE S.GPA < 3.5
```

Its made a bit more tricky, by having multiple columns for the Enrollment, rather than multiple rows in Enrollment for each student (which would be more normal)

Personally, I would convert that to a 'normalised' view:

```
SELECT StudentId, Course1 AS CourseId
FROM Enrollment E
UNION
SELECT StudentId, Course2 AS CourseId
FROM Enrollment E
UNION
SELECT StudentId, Course3 AS CourseId
FROM Enrollment E
UNION
SELECT StudentId, Course4 AS CourseId
FROM Enrollment E
```

Combine that with the first query:

```
SELECT S.Id, S.Name
FROM Student S
JOIN
(
    SELECT StudentId, Course1 AS CourseId
    FROM Enrollment E
    UNION
    SELECT StudentId, Course2 AS CourseId
    FROM Enrollment E
    UNION
    SELECT StudentId, Course3 AS CourseId
    FROM Enrollment E
    UNION
    SELECT StudentId, Course4 AS CourseId
    FROM Enrollment E
) E
  ON E.StudentId = S.StudentId
WHERE S.GPA < 3.5
```

Then you need the Actual Course to get the CreditHourRating:

```
SELECT S.Id, S.Name, C.CreditHourRating
FROM Student S
JOIN
(
    SELECT StudentId, Course1 AS CourseId
    FROM Enrollment E
    UNION
    SELECT StudentId, Course2 AS CourseId
    FROM Enrollment E
    UNION
    SELECT StudentId, Course3 AS CourseId
    FROM Enrollment E
    UNION
    SELECT StudentId, Course4 AS CourseId
    FROM Enrollment E
) E
  ON E.StudentId = S.StudentId
JOIN Course C
  ON E.CourseId = C.CourseId
WHERE S.GPA < 3.5
```

Then you only need the total for each Student, so the query becomes:

```
SELECT S.Id, S.Name, SUM(C.CreditHourRating)
FROM Student S
JOIN
(
    SELECT StudentId, Course1 AS CourseId
    FROM Enrollment E
    UNION
    SELECT StudentId, Course2 AS CourseId
    FROM Enrollment E
    UNION
    SELECT StudentId, Course3 AS CourseId
    FROM Enrollment E
    UNION
    SELECT StudentId, Course4 AS CourseId
    FROM Enrollment E
) E
  ON E.StudentId = S.StudentId
JOIN Course C
  ON E.CourseId = C.CourseId
WHERE S.GPA < 3.5
GROUP BY S.Id, S.Name
```

And lastly, you have the condition on the CreditHoursRating:

```
SELECT S.Id, S.Name, SUM(C.CreditHourRating)
FROM Student S
JOIN
(
    SELECT StudentId, Course1 AS CourseId
    FROM Enrollment E
    UNION
    SELECT StudentId, Course2 AS CourseId
    FROM Enrollment E
    UNION
    SELECT StudentId, Course3 AS CourseId
    FROM Enrollment E
    UNION
    SELECT StudentId, Course4 AS CourseId
    FROM Enrollment E
) E
  ON E.StudentId = S.StudentId
JOIN Course C
  ON E.CourseId = C.CourseId
WHERE S.GPA < 3.5
GROUP BY S.Id, S.Name
HAVING SUM(C.CreditHourRating) < 9
```

Comment: Thanks for breaking it down like that Fergus!!!!! Works perfectly, and I now understand the implementation completely. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

If the DB schema is up to you, then I'd change it a little.  Enrollment represents mappings between students and courses.  I'd simplify it to two columns: StudentID and CourseID (you can add a third column of EnrollmentID if you don't want a composite primary key for the table).

After you do this, you can join Students -> Enrollments -> Courses.  Group by StudentID and filter using a HAVING clause on the sum of a Student's credit hours and filter using a WHERE on Student GPA.

Make sense?

Comment: Interesting, but unfortunately the tables were given to us. I've never heard of the HAVING clause, so I'm looking into that now.

Comment: In that case, look in to LEFT JOINs between Enrollment and Course and SUM the ISNULL(Course.CreditHour, 0) of each Enrollment->Course relationship.  You'll end up with four left joins which represent each Enrollment->Course relationship.  Also, a HAVING clause is used to filter result sets based upon aggregate functions (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx)